# Convert SubjectPublicKeyInfo to Java PublicKey

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

My app is using bouncycastle to decode certificates deeper then java native X509Certificate provide, actualy i have bouncy castle certificates ( `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate`).

My question is how to secure convert `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo` to a `java.security.Publickey`. ?

i'd like to use the standard java signature method `java.security.Signature` instead BouncyCastle alternatives.

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(signatureAlgorithm.getAlgorithm().getId());
        sig.initVerify(getPublicKey());
        sig.update(content);
        return sig.verify(signature);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to convert the key is using a RSAKeyParameter and RSAPublicKeySpec 'to rebuild' the key using the Modulus and Exponent.

```
RSAKeyParameters rsa = (RSAKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(certificate.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsa.getModulus(), rsa.getExponent());
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
java.security.Publickey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(rsaSpec);
```

Comment: Encoding it to binary and then decoding it would be another option. SubjectPublicKeyInfo is the main encoding used for `RSAPublicKey.getEncoded()` and `X509EncodedKeySpec `. I prefer not to encode / decode though, so the above method should probably be prefered if encoding to binary is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`JcaPEMKeyConverter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.3/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMKeyConverter.html):

```java
SubjectPublicKeyInfo spki = certificate.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
PublicKey publicKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPublicKey(spki);
```

Internally it is pretty simple itself:

```java
KeyFactory keyFactory = getKeyFactory(spki.getAlgorithm());
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(spki.getEncoded()));
```